# Nodejs and improve searching with moongose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to be able to search in db more freely on a string. 
For example, Im storing name and lastnamn like "Joe Doe".

I want to be able to find him in strings like this:
Jo, Joe, Do, Doe, Joe Do, Jo Do, Do Jo, Doe Joe
And also if there is typos like Johe doe.

Im using moongose to handle my atlas DB (mongoDB).

This is what I have now which is:

```
const aggregate = [
    {
      $match: {
        category: { $regex: `${body.category}`, $options: 'i' },
      },
    }, {
      $match: {
        name: { $regex: `${body.search}`, $options: 'i' },
      },
    }
  ];


  connectToDatabase().then(() => {
    Names.aggregate(aggregate)
      .then((name) =>
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(name),
        })
      )
      .catch((err) =>
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
          },
          body: 'Could not find.',
        })
      );
  });
```

Comment: Please clarify which database you are using and post code you have already tried.

Comment: more details needed about the schema

Comment: Updating with code and more info, @Erich

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a regular expression to the find method in the Mongoose model. Lets say that your model is `User`, and you need to search something like `Jo`:

```
const findUsersLikeJo = async () => {
    const users = await User.find({name: /Jo/i})
    console.log( findUsersLikeJo() )
}
```

That is the core idea. Addapt it to your specific case. Look here for more examples: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find